# How to mock final class and static func for unit test with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, xctest

I have a class with `static` function like this.

`UserAuthentication.swift`

```
final class UserAuthentication {
    /// Check is logged in
    /// - Returns: boolean true is login, false not login
    @objc public static func isLogin() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

I want to write a unit test for `checkTermAndCondition` function which call it in my `HomeInteractor` class

`HomeInteractor.swift`

```
class HomeInteractor: HomeInteractorBusinessLogic {
    var presenter: HomePresenterInterface!
    var worker: HomeWorker = HomeWorker(with: HomeService())
    
    func checkTermAndCondition() {
        if UserAuthentication.isLogin() {
            ///do true case
        } else {
            ///do fasle case
        }
    }
}
```

Have anyone ever done it ?
Appreciate any help from you.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mock a `static` method on a `final` class.

You should either change the method to `class` and make the class non-final or even better, inject `UserAuthentication` as a protocol to `HomeInteractor` and in your unit tests, inject a mock type rather than your real production type.

```
protocol UserAuthenticator {
    /// Check is logged in
    /// - Returns: boolean true is login, false not login
    static func isLogin() -> Bool
}

final class UserAuthentication: UserAuthenticator {
    @objc public static func isLogin() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}

final class UserAuthenticationMock: UserAuthenticator {
    static var shouldLogin: Bool = false

    static func isLogin() -> Bool {
        shouldLogin
    }
}


class HomeInteractor: HomeInteractorBusinessLogic {
    var presenter: HomePresenterInterface!
    var worker: HomeWorker = HomeWorker(with: HomeService())
    let userAuthenticator: UserAuthenticator.Type

    init(userAuthenticator: UserAuthenticator.Type) {
        self.userAuthenticator = userAuthenticator
    }

    func checkTermAndCondition() {
        if userAuthenticator.isLogin() {

        } else {

        }
    }
}
```

Inject `UserAuthentication.self` for your prod code, while `UserAuthenticationMock.self` for the tests.

```
let prodHomeInteractor = HomeInteractor(userAuthenticator: UserAuthentication.self)
let testHomeInteractor = HomeInteractor(userAuthenticator: UserAuthenticationMock.self)
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer so much. Can I ask more one question what is .self mean ? it send type or reference of final class ?

Comment: @NawinPoolsawad `self` at the end of a type name returns the meta type (type of the type). That is necessary in order to access type methods (`static`).

Comment: `init(userAuthenticator: UserAuthenticator.Type)` notice `.Type`, it means you need to pass the type of UserAuthenticator. Normally we pass the instance of a class / struct to a function, in this case we are passing the UserAuthenticator type. Using the type we can call the static function on the type, we don't need an instance because we are using the static function.